# Comparison of two identical strings using String.equals() always returns as false

Tags: java, android

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, but I have wasted too much time on this already. I am getting the checksum of a NMEA sentence using:

```
String[] splitData = sentence.split("[,*]");
int i = 0;
for (char c : (sentence.substring(1, sentence.indexOf("*"))).toCharArray()) { 
    i = i ^ c;
}
String checksum = Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase();
if (!checksum.equals(splitData[splitData.length - 1].toUpperCase())) {
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Checksum failed! Expected: " +
        splitData[splitData.length - 1].toUpperCase() +
        " Got: " + checksum);
}
```

And this is what is the Log outputs:

```
NmeaParser: Checksum failed! Expected: 66 Got: 66
NmeaParser: Checksum failed! Expected: 1E Got: 1E
NmeaParser: Checksum failed! Expected: 2C Got: 2C
NmeaParser: Checksum failed! Expected: 53 Got: 53
NmeaParser: Checksum failed! Expected: 66 Got: 66
```

I have tried using toString() on both compared Strings (I know, it's redundant, but I'm desperate). I've tried trim() on both Strings to get rid of any undetected whitespace. I am baffled. The code seems pretty strait forward, and the Logs confirm the Strings are identical.

So... what am I missing here?!?

Comment: Not sure but looks like in your if statment, you have an extra exclamation mark : if( (!...) try to remove that exclamation mark

Comment: @YouneS I only see the one exclamation mark that would make the statement return true if the Strings do not match. Thanks for taking a look at it. Any input is appreciated

Comment: How is this valid: `String checksum = Integer.toHexString(checksum).toUpperCase();`?

Comment: @forpas `Integer.toHexString()` returns a String object. `String.toUpperCase()` also returns a String object. How is that not valid? What am I missing?

Comment: You declare `checksum` and initialize it at the same time by using its value?

Comment: Did you mean maybe: `String checksum = Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase();?`

Comment: @forpas Yes! I knew it was something obvious. Please put that in an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: You can't initialize a variable by itself. I wonder how this even compiled.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I typoed my question. Question updated. Sorry

Comment: Issue still occurs with update. Thanks for pointing that out @forpas

Comment: Before `if` write this: `String str = splitData[splitData.length - 1].toUpperCase();` and after that log the length of `str` and `checksum` just in case there exist unprintable chars in any of the 2.

Comment: @forpas Nice call! The length of Expected is 2, while the length of Got is 3! I just adjusted my code to trim any other characters and it works! Put that as an answer to get the credit for it. Thanks omg I feel dumb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `if` write this: 
`String str = splitData[splitData.length - 1].toUpperCase();` 
and after that log the length of `str` and `checksum` 
 just in case there exist unprintable chars in any of the 2

Comment: The length gave it away! (2 vs 3) Stupid unprintable characters! Thanks so much!